# Access denied error while connecting to MySQL in App in Azure App Service

Tags: mysql, azure, web-applications, phpmyadmin, azure-web-app-service

I created an Azure App Service and enabled MySql in App. I able to connect to MySql using phpMyAdmin from portal - go to app -> MySql in App -> click manage. It open another window with phpMyAdmin.

But somehow now I am not able to connect to database. I get below error

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 2002 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by
>   its access permissions. — The server is not responding (or the local
>   server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: Well I am not sure if the steps will work as I use App Service of Azure and do not have access to file system you mentioned. Its PaaS and I can access only source code files.

Answer (score 9):

It's simple.
If you have stopped the website and started it again, you must connect to the website URL from a browser, before you can use phpMyAdmin.

Comment: This only affects app services without Always On enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check and follow below guidelines:

1.Locate your `config.inc.php` file which relates to `PHPMyAdmin`.

2.Locate the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` mostly this line might have been commented out by default, if so please uncomment it.

3.And replace that line with following:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`

4.Save it and restart the MySQL Database from your XAMPP control panel.

5.Change your $host parameter value in the `mysqli_connect()` method to following:

```
`$_connection = mysqli_connect(**"localhost: 3306"**, $_mysql_username, $_mysql_password, $_database);`
```

**Note**: This 3306 is my MySQL port number which is its default. You should better check what's your actual MySQL Port number before going to follow these steps.

For more details you could refer to this similar [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b7f1bcac-751a-4b5c-b6b8-d568bef707b3/i-have-a-problem-with-the-access-to-phpmyadmin-on-app-service-with-mysql-in-app-on-azure).