# Socket error when connecting to In App MySQL in Azure App Service

Tags: mysql, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I have deployed an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API application to Azure App Service. I have an In App MySQL as part of the app service. When I call my API, I get the following error:

```
"ExtendedSocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:3306"
```

I looked around for a solution and found this: [Access denied error while connecting to MySQL in App in Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028539/access-denied-error-while-connecting-to-mysql-in-app-in-azure-app-service)

But the fix suggested above did not resolve the problem.

I also tried various connection strings, and all of them are causing the same exception. Here is what I have currently:

```
Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=dbname;Uid=username;Pwd=password
```

So, my question is this: What should I do to enable my ASP.NET Core API to connect to my **In App** MySql database?

PS1: There are many articles that describe how to resolve connectivity issues for Azure MySql DB (such as setting up firewall access etc), but not for In App MySQL.

Comment: How did you connect to the Database? How did you construct a connection string? Are you using the environment variable `localdb`?

Comment: Yes, I have the connection string in appsettings.json. I'm not using environment variables right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you can't configure connection string by `appsettings.json`. The Azure InApp MySQL connection string is configured automatically via the **Environment Variables** : **`MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb`**.

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#prefixes):

> The Configuration API has special processing rules for four connection string environment variables involved in configuring Azure connection strings for the app environment. Environment variables with the prefixes shown in the table are loaded into the app if no prefix is supplied to AddEnvironmentVariables.

In short, you need get the pre-defined `ConnectionString` by :

```cs
var conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("localdb");
```

What's more, the Azure **InApp MySQL `ConnectionString`** is not a **[Standard MySQL `ConnectionString`](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/standard/)**:

```
Database=localdb;Server={host_like_127.0.0.1}:{port_like_52841};Uid={azure};Pwd={random}
```

In other words, the default `ConnectionString` is not ready to be used in C#.

### How to Connect the InApp MySQL

In order to connect the InApp MySQL with `ASP.NET Core`, we need **normalize** it before passing it to `UseMySQL(conn)`. Here's my dirty code that normalize the default InApp ConnectionString:

```cs
private string NormalizeAzureInAppConnString(string raw) {
    string conn = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        var dict =
             raw.Split(';')
                 .Where(kvp => kvp.Contains('='))
                 .Select(kvp => kvp.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2))
                 .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp[0].Trim(), kvp => kvp[1].Trim(), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        var ds = dict["Data Source"];
        var dsa = ds.Split(":");
        conn = $"Server={dsa[0]};Port={dsa[1]};Database={dict["Database"]};Uid={dict["User Id"]};Pwd={dict["Password"]};";
    }
    catch {
        throw new Exception("unexpected connection string: datasource is empty or null");
    }
    return conn;
}
```

And then you can register the DbContext as below:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>{
    var conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("localdb");
    options.UseMySql( NormalizeAzureInAppConnString(conn) );
});
```

It should work now.

### Demo

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will test this out and update here.

Comment: itminus, thanks a lot! It is working now. The socket error is gone. Just one observation, though. My schema was different from localdb, but when I used var conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("mydb"), it wouldn't connect, i.e., it only works with localdb.

Is there any restriction which mandates localdb for MySql InApp?

Comment: @SirG As far as I know, the name `localdb` is configured by Azure environment variables `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb`.You can't change this name. But as a walkaround, you could use `phpMyAdmin` to change your database.

Comment: you're a savior. Big thanx